# OpenTok publisher's view becomes black when application enters in foreground

Tags: background, opentok

In my one to one video calling app using OpenTok, the publisher's view becomes black after it goes to background mode and enters foreground. The subscriber is also not able to see the view(only seeing black box).

I am setting the publisher and subscriber properties as such:

`publisher.publishVideo = true`

`subscriber.subscribeToVideo = true`

Any solution will be very helpful.

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. Could you please share which platform you're using? (iOS or Android)

Comment: We are using iOS platform

Comment: It's important to note that you need to make some changes so you can run the application in background mode while in an OpenTok Session and reclaim the publisher's video when you come back into foreground. 

For more information, please visit: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/background-state.html

Comment: i am calling doPublish() Again when application comes in foreground but it gives me a error in result.

' Error Domain=OTSessionErrorDomain Code=1011 "(null)" '

here is my code,

lazy var publisher: OTPublisher = {
        let settings = OTPublisherSettings()
        settings.videoTrack = isVideoEnable
        settings.audioTrack = true
        settings.name = UIDevice.current.name
        return OTPublisher(delegate: self, settings: settings)!
    }(

Comment: func doPublish() {
 publisher.publishAudio = true
        publisher.publishVideo = true
        publisher.cameraPosition = .front
        session?.publish(publisher, error: &error)
        
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        
        guard publisher.view != nil else {
            return
        }
        publishView = publisher.view
}

Comment: Hey Syed, you cannot publish the same publisher when it's already publishing. Could you file an issue in the following repo so I can help you debug further? 
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift

Comment: Done!
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift/issues/75

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue on android.